# php script taking longer than max_execution_time

Tags: php, time

i am trying to limit the maximum time of php script.
in php.ini i have 30seconds.

in a script i wrote:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3);
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');

$cp=1;
while (1 == 1) {
  $cp++;
  $date = @date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  echo "<li>$cp $date";
} 
?>
```

But when on the browser i get the first line:

2019-02-19 19:43:38
and on the last:
302688 2019-02-19 19:44:15

I dont understand, it should stop after 3 seconds:
so at 19:43:41

Thanks all,
good evening

Comment: Check if ini_set is returning "true", probably you are trying to set a setting that is inside a per-host system.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to calculate the microtime running a script. Something like:

```
<?php
$start_time = microtime(true);

while (microtime(true)-$start_time<3)
{
  $date=@date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  echo "<LI>$cp $date";
}
?>
```